# Data tag parsing failed: Encountered multiple top tags, only one expected

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

The command tag I have been using is as follows:

```
/summon EntityHorse ~ ~ ~ {Type: 3, Tame: 1, Saddle: 1} Attributes[Name:Horse Jumpstrength, Base:10,Name:Generic.Movementspeed, Base:20, Name:Generic.maxhealth, Base:5000]
```

I have also tried the following command:

```
/summon EntityHorse ~ ~ ~ {Type: 3, Tame: 1, Saddle: 1} Attributes:[{Name:Horse Jumpstrength, Base:10,Name:Generic.Movementspeed, Base:20, Name:Generic.maxhealth, Base:5000}]
```

Neither of them seem to be working. I am running on Minecraft version 1.10.2 on a windows desktop. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

NBT input for the command belongs in a single root compound. Compounds surround their data with curly brackets. However, you closed the root compound after the `Saddle` tag, breaking syntax.

The `Attributes` tag is a list. A list tag surrounds a collection of data (separated by commas) within square brackets. In particular, `Attributes` is a list consisting of compounds.

Each compound within `Attributes` is a single attribute. You must separate each attribute into their own compound. There are also incorrect values being used. Attribute IDs are case-sensitive; instead of "Generic.Movementspeed", you need "generic.movementSpeed", instead of "Generic.maxhealth", you need "generic.maxHealth", and instead of "Horse Jumpstrength" you need "horse.jumpStrength".

The maximum attribute value for "generic.maxHealth" is 1024, and the maximum value for "horse.jumpStrength" is 2. You'll find that a "generic.movementSpeed" value of 20 is overkill, but the maximum is 1024.

And finally, the `Saddle` tag is deprecated. You should be using `SaddleItem` instead, which is a compound containing item data for the saddle.

Fixed command:

```
/summon EntityHorse ~ ~ ~ {Type:3,Tame:1b,SaddleItem:{id:"minecraft:saddle",Count:1b},Attributes:[{Name:"horse.jumpStrength",Base:2.0},{Name:"generic.movementSpeed",Base:20.0},{Name:"generic.maxHealth",Base:1024.0}]}
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to put that horse in a mob spawn egg, now?